# Beginner issues with Eclipse and running an imported .jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, import

I've never used Eclipse before am trying to import a .jar file and then run it without any command-line arguments.

I think the .jar file has been imported correctly, it is sitting in a created lib folder and I  can see it in referenced libraries.

The .jar will not run because of the error "selection does not contain a main type".

I can see there is a main class inside the .jar when I extract it, but the manifest file does not include a 'main-class' specification. Because this is an assignment though, I cannot alter the .jar directory. Is there a way that I can run the file within Eclipse regardless of this?

Within the jar file all classes are part of a package. Would this alter the way I could try and run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure, you imported the JAR correctly: In package explorer, right click your project, choose Properties, Java Build Path and tab Libraries. If your library doesn't appear, click button Add JARs or Add External JARs and choose your JAR file.

Then right click your project and choose Run As / Run Configurations.
In the dialog window click button New launch configuration. Then on the right side under Main class, input the full qualified class name of the main class which is contained in your JAR file. E.g. `com.foo.Bar` for class `Bar` in package `com.foo`. You can use the button Search to search for a main class.

Then click Apply and Run.

Answer (score 0):

Write a class that will call the main class inside the jar.
Or simply ask your instructor.